# New row after a set of value is done

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array with these values:

```
[
    "Prod1",
    "Puma Superstar",
    "1",
    "$50",
    "Prod2",
    "Nike Superstar",
    "2",
    "$100"
]
```

Is it possible to do it like this?

```
Product ID   |   Product Name   | Qty | Price
-------------|------------------|-----|------
   Prod1     |   Puma Superstar |  1  | $50
   Prod2     |   Nike Superstar |  2  | $100
```

My code  is showing what I've tried to do. However, due to the `rows.length` always being at 0 (not refreshed), I can't add items into a new row. Is there a way or it's not possible?

```js
  db.allDocs({
    include_docs: true,
    attachments: true,
    startkey: 'receipt',
    endkey: 'receipt\uffff'
  }).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    console.log(result.rows.length);
    for (var i = 0; i <= (result.rows.length - 1); i++) {
      if (result.rows[i].doc.nric == "alvin123") {
        var tableRef = document.getElementById("tableA").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

        var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);

        var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
        var anotherCell = newRow.insertCell(1);

        newCell.onclick = function() {

          var id = this.innerHTML;

          alert(id);

          db.get(id).then(function(doc) {

            var tableRef1 = document.getElementById("tableC").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

            var tableLength = tableRef1.rows.length;

            var newRow1 = tableRef1.insertRow(tableLength);

            var newCell1 = newRow1.insertCell(0);
            var anotherCell1 = newRow1.insertCell(1);
            var newCell2 = newRow1.insertCell(2);
            var anotherCell3 = newRow1.insertCell(3);


            for (var j = 0; j < doc.items[0].length; j++) {

              if (doc.items[0][j].charAt(0) == 'P') {
                newCell1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(doc.items[0][j]));

              } else if (doc.items[0][j].charAt(0) == '$') {
                anotherCell3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(doc.items[0][j]));
                tableLength = tableLength + 1;
              } else if (isNaN(doc.items[0][j].charAt(0)) == false) {
                newCell2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(doc.items[0][j]));
              } else {
                anotherCell1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(doc.items[0][j]));
              }
            }

          }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
          });

        };

        newCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result.rows[i].doc._id));
        anotherCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode("$" + result.rows[i].doc.totalAmount));
      }
    }
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: Please include the code for your array variable definition.

Comment: please specify doc variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is way to complicated. Look at this simple example:

```
var tableRef1 = document.getElementById("tableC").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

var items = [
  "Prod1",
  "Puma Superstar",
  "1",
  "$50",
  "Prod2",
  "Nike Superstar",
  "2",
  "$100"
]

for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j+=4) {

  var tableLength = tableRef1.rows.length;
  var newRow = tableRef1.insertRow(tableLength);
  var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);

  cell1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(items[j]));
  cell2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(items[j+1]));
  cell3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(items[j+2]));
  cell4.appendChild(document.createTextNode(items[j+3]));
}
```

Note that:

- You need to add rows to your table **inside** the loop
- You don't have to check the first character of the current value. You know they are always in the same order - just take the next four items. That's why my loop counter increments by four.

See this working example at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zn710ytk/).

Answer (score 0):

create an array object and push the values into that object.

```
var tableRef1 = []
 tableRef1.push(document.getElementById("tableC").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0])
```

`

Now this tableRef can be modified to add further values.

Answer (score 0):

If your data will be consistent on the exact fields, chunked it down into size 4 and then continue with inserting it in your row:

```js
var prod = [
              "Prod1",
              "Puma Superstar",
              "1",
              "$50",
              "Prod2",
              "Nike Superstar",
              "2",
              "$100"
]

function chunk(arr, size){
  var chunkedArr = [];
  var noOfChunks = Math.ceil(arr.length/size);
  console.log(noOfChunks);
  for(var i=0; i<noOfChunks; i++){
    chunkedArr.push(arr.slice(i*size, (i+1)*size));
  }
   return chunkedArr;
}

var chunkedArr = chunk(prod, 4);
console.log(chunkedArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that your array is constantly dividing into four index or must generate a new row every after four index. Below is a sample code how to chunk it.

```js
var arr_ = [
    "Prod1",
    "Puma Superstar",
    "1",
    "$50",
    "Prod2",
    "Nike Superstar",
    "2",
    "$100"
];
var ctr = 0;
var arr_obj = [];
for(var x=0; x<(arr_.length/4); x++){
  arr_obj.push({
    'Product ID' : arr_[ctr + 0],
    'Product Name' : arr_[ctr + 1],
    'Qty' : arr_[ctr + 2], 
    'Price' : arr_[ctr + 3]
  }); 
  ctr += x+4;  
}
console.log(arr_obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets first generate a data object called `tableData` which is compatible with the `tableMaker` function. Then it's just a matter of simple `tableMaker(tableData, true)` call. The `true` argument designates that the resulted table html string will include the object property keys as hearder tags `textContent` (`<th>Property Key</th>`)

```js
function tableMaker(o,h){
  var keys = Object.keys(o[0]),
  rowMaker = (a,t) => a.reduce((p,c,i,a) => p + (i === a.length-1 ? "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + "></tr>"
                                                                  : "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + ">"),"<tr>"),
      rows = o.reduce((r,c) => r + rowMaker(keys.reduce((v,k) => v.concat(c[k]),[]),"td"),h ? rowMaker(keys,"th") : []);
  return "<table>" + rows + "</table>";
}

var  data = ["Prod1", "Puma Superstar", "1", "$50",
             "Prod2", "Nike Superstar", "2", "$100"],
tableData = data.reduce((p,c,i,a) => i%4 === 0 ? p.concat({"Product ID":c, "Product Name":a[++i], "Quantity":a[++i], "Price":a[++i]})
                                               : p,[]),
tableHTML = tableMaker(tableData,true);
myTable.innerHTML = tableHTML;
```

```html
<div id="myTable"></div>
```